# ASP.NET MVC Core 3.0 after login shows login page again at the browser back button click

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

Once the user gets logged in and press the back button then the user needs to login again. I want to solve this issue. Can anyone have idea about it?

[image: Error Screen]

```
//startup.cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options=>
{
     options.Cookie.Name = "Dementia.Cookie";
     //options.EventsType = typeof(Infrastructure.Persistance.GenericUser);
     options.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
     options.LogoutPath = "/Home/Logout";
     options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); //TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
     options.SlidingExpiration = false;             
});

 //Controller
 [Authorize]
 [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
 public IActionResult Dashboard()
 {
      return View();
 }
```

Comment: Do you use `app.UseAuthentication();` in `Configure` method  and place it in correct order after `app.UseRouting();` before `app.UseAuthorization();` and `app.UseEndpoints()`

Comment: Please find below my order app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

Comment: Xing Zou@ Can you see my order and let me know if any wrong.

Comment: It's in right order.What do you mean `shows login page again at the browser back button click`,could you come into the action decorated with authorize attribute？

Comment: After adding Authorize that is working fine but problem with login still Master page(_Layout.chtml) staying logged in. Should i need to authenticated anything in Header Page (_Layout.chtml) ?

Comment: Xing Zou@ Shared screen shot above after back button click user is still authenticated and logged in. How can i remove this or should i need to add or missing any functionality?

Comment: So，why do you need to click the back button instead of redirecting user to the previous page after login like what Identity does.Do you have problem if you refresh the dashboard page after login?

Comment: I don't want to go back navigation after login and also when user click browser back navigation after login same page need to refresh instead of go login page. How to do that in asp.net core 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manually stored in cookies dashboard url and validate the identity its working fine.

```
 var claims = new[] {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userInfo.Name),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userInfo.Category),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Uri, "/Home/Dashboard"),
                        new Claim("UserId", userInfo.UserId),
                        new Claim("Id", userInfo.Id)};

public IActionResult Login()
    {
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Redirect(HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Uri).Value);
        }
        return View();
    }
```